# Extending Math object through prototype doesn't work

Tags: javascript, math, prototype, built-in

I try to extend JavaScript `Math`. But one thing surprised me.

When I tried to extend it by `prototype`

```
Math.prototype.randomBetween = function (a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
};
```

In console I have error 'Cannot set property 'randomBetween' of undefined' ...

But if I asigne this function to `Math.__proto__`

```
Math.__proto__.randomBetween = function (a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
};
```

Then everything works fine.

Can anybody explain me why it works in this way? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`Math` isn't a constructor, so it doesn't have `prototype` property:

```
new Math(); // TypeError: Math is not a constructor
```

Instead, just add your method to `Math` itself as an [own property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.30):

```
Math.randomBetween = function (a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
};
```

Your approach with `__proto__` works because, since `Math` is an `Object` instance, `Math.__proto__` is `Object.prototype`.

But then note you are adding `randomBetween` method to all objects, not only to `Math`. This can be problematic, for example when iterating objects with a `for...in` loop.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Why do you not like "own property"?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty an "own property" in JavaScript is a property that exists directly on a particular object (as opposed to one that is inherited via the prototype chain). Maybe it would be easier to look at if it had quotes around it or were in italics?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, quotes would help though otherwise it looks like mangled English

Answer (score 5):

That's because there's  `Math` is an object, *not* a `function`.

In javascript, a `function` is the rough equivalent of a class in object oriented languages.  `prototype` is a special property which lets you  add instance methods to this class<sup>1</sup>.  When you want to extend that class, you use `prototype` and it "just works".

Now let's think about what `Math` is.  You never create a math object, you just use it's methods.  In fact, it doesn't make sense to create two different `Math` objects, because `Math` always works the same!  In other words, the `Math` object in javascript is just a convenient way to group a bunch of pre-written math related functions together.  It's like a dictionary of common math.

Want to add something to that group?  Just add a property to the collection!  Here's two easy ways to do it.

```
Math.randomBetween = function() { ... }
Math["randomBetween"] = function() {... }
```

Using the second way makes it a bit more obvious that it's a dictionary type collection, but they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

To quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572996/1317805):

> Some JavaScript implementations allow direct access to the [[Prototype]] property, eg via a non-standard property named `__proto__`. In general, it's only possible to set an object's prototype during object creation: If you create a new object via new Func(), the object's [[Prototype]] property will be set to the object referenced by Func.prototype.

The reason you can't assign to its prototype using `.prototype` is because the `Math` object has already been created.

Fortunately for us, we can assign new properties to the `Math` object by simply using:

```
Math.myFunc = function() { return true };
```

In your case, this would be:

```
Math.randomBetween = function(...) { ... };
```

Comment: To be fair as much as I hate `__proto__` it has since been standardized and works on all modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```
var MyMath = Object.create(Math); // empty object with prototype Math

MyMath.randomBetween = function (a, b) {
    return this.floor(this.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
};

typeof(MyMath);                 // object
Object.getPrototypeOf(MyMath);  // Math
MyMath.PI;                      // 3.14...
MyMath.randomBetween(0, 10);    // exactly that
```

- the `Math` object is the prototype of the new `MyMath` object
- `MyMath` has access to all functionality of `Math`
- you can add your custom functionality to `MyMath` without manipulating `Math`
- within your custom methods, use keyword `this` to refer to the `Math` functionality

There is no *Monkey Patching* with this approach. This is the best way to extend JavScript `Math`. There is no need to repeat the explanations from the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

While `Math` is an actual `Object` not a `constructible class` you can use `spread operator: {...obj}` to extend the Math Object like this:

```js
const ExtendMath = {
    ...Math,
    randomInt(max, min = 0){Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min},
}
```

now the `randomInt()` method will be added to the `Math` object as an extended method.

Comment: The `Math` object won't be changed. Did you mean "will be added to the Math object"?

Comment: yes exactly, it will not be added directly to the `Math` object but it will be added to the `ExtendMath` object.

Comment: but in your answer, you say the "method will be added to the Math object"